# Remove a row based on a value in a column using if statements

Tags: r, function, for-loop, if-statement

I'm hoping to create a function in which it removes a row if the value in column B is less than the mean of the entire column.

```
testing<-function(x){
for(n in x){
    if(n < mean(n){
    *drop the entire row*
    }
```

So far, I am only able to get R to delete the value itself, but not the entire row, so a sample way of using this function would be

```
df$columnB <- testing(df$columnB)
```

so the input for the function itself is only from one of the columns, but inside the function it needs to know to delete the entire row and not just that column, so just drop(n) would not suffice.

Used the following to test it out:

```
iris_tibble<-as_tibble(iris)

#all values became NA and message saying "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"
testing <- function(x) {
  i <- x[,"Sepal.Length"] < mean(x[,"Sepal.Length"])
  return( x[!i,] )
}
testing(iris_tibble)

#Goal
testing <- function(x,y){
  i <- x[,y] < mean(x[,y])
  return( x[!i,] )
}

testing(iris_tibble,"Sepal.Length")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough:

```r
testing <- function(x, colname) {
    i <- x[,colname] < mean(x[,colname,drop=TRUE])
    return( x[!i,] )
}

dim( iris )
dim( testing( as_tibble(iris), "Sepal.Length" ) )

## cust roughly half of iris away
```

you should give it your entire data.frame and a column name, eg. `testing(df, "foobar")`, and capture what it retuns.

Comment: Thank you! Based on your answer, I tried to make the column B thing flexible in that, I set it to function(x,y) then replace all "columnB" to y in the code, cause sometimes the column has different names and position. But it generated an error code saying "'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'", but when I glimpse() nothing is a list, is it not possible to make the code work that way?

Comment: you would have to include all or parts of your data in the question at this point

Comment: Don't have a dataset going yet, but I copied the iris data for now to test it out and updated the question to include it at the bottom

Comment: see my updated answer, running on iris as an example.. and for a tibble you need drop=TRUE in there, see the updated answer

Comment: Thanks so much! And if I want to pre-calculate the mean, so that the line assigning i can be cleaner especially if I add more to the formula (e.g. mean x 2), will the following be correct? ```testing <- function(x, colname) {
  mean_col = mean(x[,colname,drop=TRUE])
    i <- x[,colname] < mean_col*2
    return(x[!i,])
}```

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean, but your code there would just end up filtering away rows less than double the mean, which would mean a lot more rows get fitlered

Comment: Yes, perfect, thats what I was hoping to try out too. I just wanted to make sure its okay to set this ```mean_col = mean(x[,colname,drop=TRUE])``` a line before ```i <- x[,colname] < mean_col*2``` and it will still be correct in terms of syntax

Comment: Ok, well yes, it will